# Image and text in floating object

Tags: html, css

For most of you this will be a simple question but I'm new to css. My problem is that I have two blocks next to each other with float but text in second object just does not stay in same line. How do I get everything in same line?

What it should look like:
[blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT3vI.jpg)
In reality everything works fine until "Text2" comes or I try to adjust "Logo" padding, then "Text2" moves to next line something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVS5j.jpg).

Also how do I get "Text2" next to "Logo"? Right now I only got it working with **float:right** but I need it closer to the logo. And do I use **aside** for these elements? Thanks.

Adding js fiddle url for demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/08rhr7wx/

HTML:

```
<aside>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="block1">
<h2>Text1</h2>
</div>
<div class="block2"><img src="img/logo.jpg"></div>
<h2>Text2</h2>
</div>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper .block1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #390b5d;
  width: 555px;
}   

.wrapper .block1 h2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 13px;
}

.wrapper .block2 {
  float: left;
  width: 325px;
  background: #e26c34;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.wrapper .block2 h2 {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `.wrapper .block2 h2` ?? h2 is not inside your `block2` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved your "text2" inside the `block2` where I guess you want it.

Also, when setting up fixed width like you have, you need to set a `min-width` on the `wrapper` to keep those floats in 1 line.

To make the "text2" stay next to your logo, I changed it to `display: inline` instead of its default `display: block`.

Note: What you really should try, is to re-structure your code making it more responsive.

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper .block1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #390b5d;
  width: 555px;
}   

.wrapper .block1 h2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.wrapper .block2 {
  float: left;
  width: 325px;
  background: #e26c34;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.wrapper .block2 h2 {
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block1">
      <h2>Text1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg">
      <h2>Text2</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

As requested, a second sample where some restructure has been made.

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper div {
  height: 55px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.wrapper .block1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #390b5d;
  width: 555px;
  line-height: 55px;
}   

.wrapper .block1 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper .block2 {
  float: left;
  width: 325px;
  background: #e26c34;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 55px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.wrapper .block2 span {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper .block2 img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block1">
      <span>Text1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30/technics/5/"><span>Text2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the text in place but how do I center logo vertically? If I add `padding-top` then it changes height of whole block and makes it larger.
Also, I added `line-height: 55px;` in `.wrapper div {` to get text centered vertically, but I don't think it's really centered, can I add some extra padding from bottom?

Comment: @xantoo I will add a sample to my answer soon.

Comment: I got text padding working, just changed line-height number, so I'm left with logo centering.

Comment: @xantoo Updated my answer with a second sample to show one way to center.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding h2 tag inside .block2
`<div class="block2"><img src="img/logo.jpg"><h2>Text2</h2></div>`

Ref: jsfiddle.net/08rhr7wx/1/